# How to best use Python 3's mimetypes module in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mime-types

I deployed a working Flask application to AWS Lambda via Zappa. One of the things working locally but not on Lambda is the call to

```
mimetypes.guess_extension
```

In particular, locally, on my Mac, the guessed extension for

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

is properly

```
.docx
```

but on Lambda, it's

```
None
```

The way `mimetypes` works is that it consults the host machine's `mime.types` file, and this file either does not exist on Lambda or something does but it does not have many types.

So how can get this module to work on Lambda? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) mentions an `init` function in the module which accepts files, but that doesn't seem right for a Lambda. I could, I guess bundle up the entire 48K mime.types file on my Mac into my deployed Lambda (as a file?), but that seems like overkill, and was wondering if perhaps I missed something and that Lambdas *should* have access to this information without uploading files?

I checked PyPI and found the packages `mime` and `common-mimetypes` but they have not been touched in years.

Any best practices I am overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think based on the structure of AWS lambda, it won't contain what you want or at least all of you want.

Instead of uploading a file to lambda, I will suggest to upload the file to some cloud storage like your s3 storage. And initialize your program using that file without storing it on disk.

```
mime = MimeTypes()
with requests.get(url) as res:
    mime_file = BytesIO(res.content)
mime.readfp(mime_file)

mime.guess_extension("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well and preferred the following steps. Given that the mime.types file was 61KB this is not a lot of space relative to other packages I am installing anyway etc.

1. Locate the mime.types file on your laptop. Mine was at `/etc/apache2/mime.types`. A good list of files to check is the `mimetypes.knownfiles` list which on my machine is:

```
['/etc/mime.types', '/etc/httpd/mime.types', '/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', '/etc/apache/mime.types', '/etc/apache2/mime.types', '/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', '/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types', '/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', '/usr/local/etc/mime.types']
```

2. Copy that file to your Lambda (I am building my Lambda from a Docker Image hosted on ECR, so I just added `COPY mime.types /etc/mime.types` to that Dockerfile).
3. [Optional] If you were able to copy the file to one of the `knownfiles` locations (e.g. `/etc/mime.types`) you are done. If not, make sure to call `mimetypes.init(files=[<filename>])` in the file that needs the mimetypes type inference where `<filename>` is the path to the mimetype file location.